What reason do we have to think that the standard model of arithmetic captures our intuition of $\mathbb{N}$ better than the non-standard models?
Here's what I know: the Paris-Harrington and Goldstein Theorems show us that the 'arithmetic segment' of ZFC, interpreting $\mathbb{N}$ as $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},...\}$, is a stronger theory than first-order PA. From this, we can argue that there must be other ways to interpret $\mathbb{N}$ and its basic operations in ZFC, and from what I understand all such models are called non-standard. But is there any obvious reason to assume why the specific interpretation (the standard model) of $\mathbb{N}$ as $\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},...\}$ is the correct one and gives the correct answer? Could it be that one of these non-standard models is more intuitively aligned with our concept of $\mathbb{N}$ than the standardly chosen one is? Forgive me if the question is a little weird. My only book I've gone through even slightly in the direction of this topic is Elements of Set Theory by Enderton.

Would it be satisfying if I left an answer explaining why nonstandard models of arithmetic have to have "infinite numbers"? That is, for $\mathbb{N}$ we know that you can get every $x$ by hitting zero with successors some number of times. But in a nonstandard model, there must be some $x$s in the model which are not a successor of a successor of ... a successor of zero. I would argue this is a pretty pathological thing to have in the intuitive version of $\mathbb{N}$ we all have in our heads.

Well, they aren't all non-standard. The ones that lead to different theorems from the standard $\mathbb N$ are non-standard.

@ChrisGrossack There's something I'm missing. Am I conflating being a standard model with being isomorphic to the particular model where $\mathbb{N}$ is ${\emptyset,{\emptyset},{\emptyset,{\emptyset}},...}$ with the usual operations?

In my experience when people talk about the "standard model" of PA they don't mean the structure ${\emptyset, { \emptyset }, \ldots }$ on-the-nose. They just mean something isomorphic to it. So a "nonstandard model" is a model of PA that is not isomorphic to ${ \emptyset, { \emptyset }, \ldots }$ with the standard operations, and one can show that any such model has these infinite elements
